# React input value changing from defined to undefined after validation + submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, react-hooks

I would like to validate the info in a react form before submitting it.
Here I set up a custom react hook where I implemented both the change handling and the form submission:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

const useForm = (validate) => {

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        subject: '',
        message: '',
        disabled: null,
        emailSent: null
    });

    // Handles user input data
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        setValues ({
            ...values,
            [name] : value
        });
    }

    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

    const [isSending, setIsSending] = useState(false);

    
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        setErrors(validate(values));

        setValues({
            disabled: true
        })

        if (errors.length === 0) {

            setIsSending(true);

            // Sends POST request to the API endpoint with the given data and returns sending status
            Axios.post('http://localhost:3030/email/send', values)
            .then(res => {
                if(res.data.success) {
                    this.setValues({
                        disabled: false,
                        emailSent: true
                    });
                    this.setIsSending(false);
                } else {
                    this.setValues({
                        disabled: false,
                        emailSent: false
                    });
                    this.setIsSending(false);
                } 
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setValues({
                    disabled: false,
                    emailSent: false
                });
                setIsSending(false);
            });
        } else {
            setValues({
                disabled: false
            })
        }
    }

    return { handleChange, handleSubmit, values, errors, isSending };

}

export default useForm;
```

The validation hook is something like this:

```js
export default function validateInfo(values) {
    let errors = {};

    // Full Name validation
    if (values.name === '') {
        errors.name = 'Name is required';
    }

    // Email validation
    if (values.email === '') {
        errors.email = 'Email address is required';
    } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(values.email)) {
        errors.email = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    // Subject validation
    if (values.subject === '') {
        errors.subject = 'Subject is required';
    }

    // Message validation
    if (values.message === '') {
        errors.message = 'Please, leave me a message';
    }

    return errors;
}
```

When I debugged the application I could see that the FormControl is changing value from defined (the default " " or any data) to "undefined" just after clicking Submit, which means that the component is forcing the input to change from Controlled to Uncontrolled, in other words, it is not keeping in control the field and it also resets the errors value.

I'm sure the problem is from the handleChange() but everything looks fine to me, I will be so thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in handleSubmit you miss spread values ?

```
    setValues({
     ...values,
     disabled: true,
    });
```